# reading variables value from text file in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

In my BAT file, i want to read these data from .txt file and need to set each data into one variable

```
    SQLUserName=MFiles
    WrapperSQLServerName=usa.com
    WrapperDatabase=Wrapper
    WrapperAssemblyLocation=D:\Assembly
    MFilesNetworkAddress=USA-S1
    MFilesVaultName=MF2
    MFilesUsername=User
    MFilesPassword=
    MFilesVaultGUID={26F30-E120-408C-8035-04D85D6}
    MFilesWebServerURL=www.WebServer.com
    SQLMailProfileName=NoReply
    WrapperSupportEmail=thejus@WebServer.com
```

I tried with this code

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a IN ('find "WrapperSupportEmail" ^<config.txt') DO SET SupportEmail=%%a
```

But it throws error

```
find is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
```

Please help me

Thejus T V

Comment: Try running `find` in an interactive command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is correct one only. Only issue is windows cant locate **find.exe**. I included the .exe on same location and after that everything works fine.

Its working fine in Win 7 and Win 10 without adding **Find.exe**

Answer (score 3):

If the schema of your input file is fixed (keyword=value) and you want to assign all values to an environment variabel named keyword it is very, very easy. try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %i in (config.txt) do set %i=%j
```

remember to change %i and %j to %%i and %%j if you want to put this call into a cmd-file.

Comment: as the file is fine formatted: `for /f "delims=" %i in (config.txt) do set %i`

Comment: Text file always in the same for formatted as show above.So how we can set each key value into one variable?

Comment: As indicated in @Stephan's comment above yours. It is equivalent to execute: `set SQLUserName=MFiles`, then `set WrapperSQLServerName=usa.com`, etc...

Comment: @Aacini I want to read the data from .txt file and set to a variable from Batch file

Comment: @thejustv: Please, modify your original question and insert an additional description that _clearly_ state what you want as result!

Answer (score 0):

when two members with high reputation tell you it works, then it shouldn't be the worst of all ideas to at least try it.

```
rem @echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (config.txt) do set _%%i
pause
set _
```

I `REM`d the `@echo off`, so you can watch, how every single line get's processed.

(Your original error `find is not recognized ...` is probably because you messed up your `%path%`-variable, but you don't need `find` for this task.)